# How do I keep an overlay open by default with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, overlay

Hey guys I have a login overlay with the following code:

```
<!-- The overlay -->
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">

<!-- Login goes here -->

<!-- End login -->
</div>

<!-- Use any element to open/show the overlay navigation menu -->
<span onclick="openNav()">open</span>
```

I'm using Javascript to open it, and removed the close button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

/* Close when someone clicks on the "x" symbol inside the overlay */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}

</script>
```

My question is how do I keep the default set to open? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is your css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if i understand the problem.... and how your CSS is setup...

With just some good old CSS

```
#myNav {
 width:100%;
}
```

That way its always 100% with when the page loads and you manage its width with user interaction in javascript.

Comment: Ha! That did it! I had my width set to 0 for some reason, I've got CSS and HTML down but am just learning Javascript so I thought the issue would lie somewhere there. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! If it answered your question please mark it as the answer :) Thanks!